Why do a string and integer with identical memory values print differently?
I'm making my way through Learn C the Hard Way, in which the author often asks students to intentionally "break" the examples to learn debugging.
In Exercise 11, it's suggested to attempt to print a string as an integer. Simple enough, but in the following code, why doesn't name output the same as number when both are printed as integers?
My code, simplified:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   // This should be equal to 5318008, according to my terrible Python code.
   char name[4] = {'x', '%', 'Q', 0};
   int number = 5318008;
   printf("%d\n", name);
   printf("%d\n", number);
   return 0;
}

Output when run:
% ./temp
1962793460
5318008

The output of gdb, showing these variables are the same in memory (as best I can tell with my limited experience):
% gdb --quiet ./temp
Reading symbols from ./temp...
(gdb) break 7
Breakpoint 1 at 0x116e: file ./temp.c, line 7.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/asdfadf/Documents/c/temp

This GDB supports auto-downloading debuginfo from the following URLs:
  <https://debuginfod.archlinux.org>
Enable debuginfod for this session? (y or [n])
Debuginfod has been disabled.
To make this setting permanent, add 'set debuginfod enabled off' to .gdbinit.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, main () at ./temp.c:7
7          printf("%d\n", name);
(gdb) x/4xb &name
0x7fffffffd9e4: 0x78    0x25    0x51    0x00
(gdb) x/4xb &number
0x7fffffffd9e0: 0x78    0x25    0x51    0x00
(gdb)


name is a pointer, so your are printing the address it points to, which has nothing to do with the bytes that are stored there.

@asdfadf, Save time and enable all compiler warnings.  Faster than posting on SO.

printf("%d\n", name); does not pass the bytes in name to printf. It passes the address of name (technically the address of its first element) to printf.
For %d, printf expects an int. When you pass an address instead, the behavior is not defined by the C standard. Often (but not always), the result is to print the address, or some portion of it, as a decimal numeral. This numeral is unrelated to whatever values were stored in memory at the address.
When you pass a string to printf with a %s specification, the address is also passed, but printf knows that, for a string, it must fetch the bytes from memory. So it takes the address that it was passed and uses it to load bytes from memory and print them. This does not occur with %d; the value for %d must be passed directly, not via an address.
If you want to reinterpret the bytes in name as a number, you can do that as shown here:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // Declares memcpy.

int main(void)
{
   char name[4] = {'x', '%', 'Q', 0};
   int t;                       // Define a temporary variable.
   memcpy(&t, name, sizeof t);  // Copy bytes into t.
   printf("%d\n", t);           // Show value of t.
}

Note that different C implementations may represent int in different ways, notably by using different orders for the bytes in it, so different C implementations may print different values. Different C implementations may also use fewer or more than four bytes for int. The values of the characters “x”, “%”, and “Q” may also vary.

So my intentionally broken code was worse than I thought. That's a good reason not to write code this way and interesting insight into how things work behind the scenes.

Note, to ensure you're dealing with 32-bit ints, you may wish to include <stdint.h> and use int32_t.

There are a few things in play here. First, as Eric pointed out, you're passing the address of name, not the contents (although you would use %p instead of %d to print that properly). But even if you cast and dereferenced the argument so as to interpret the contents of that array as an integral type, it wouldn't necessarily print the same as the other:
Some CPUs store the bytes of a multibyte object out of order. This is called the endianness of the representation. Intel chips are little-endian, where the least significant byte is stored at the front (as are most other modern systems. I think Apple used to use big-endian chips, but I'm not sure).  So (for a 32-bit unsigned int), 0x00112233 would actually be stored as { 0x33, 0x22, 0x11, 0x00 }.
And one final issue when interpreting an array of char as an int is alignment. An int isn't necessarily allowed to start at any point in memory. The details will vary from system to system, but usually an object of type T needs to start at an address a s.t. 0 == a % sizeof(T) (or at least sizeof(int), if T is larger). So if that array of char starts at an odd address, you're likely to get a bus error if you try to treat it as an int.
p.s. One place where you do see big-endian representations is in network packets: since we might want to transmit an int to a system using a different endianness than ours, we first convert it into network-endian (big-endian) order, and then the receiving system converts it to its native endianness. Which, in practice, means that every system converts from little-endian to big-endian just so the receiving system can convert it back again, since nobody uses big-endian representations anymore. But changing the standard at this point would be more trouble than it's worth.

I did actually have to swap the character order around to get the memory values to read the same. I figured it had something to do with endianness.

@asdfadf POSIX has some byte order functions to handle that adjustment automatically. Also, if you ever need to do this in real code for whatever reason, a way to force the alignment to be valid is to cram everything in a union: union Foo { unsigned x, char[sizeof(unsigned)] arr }; guarantees that the unsigned int is properly aligned, and since the char[] starts at the same place, it will be, too. For signed int, you still need to deal with the different possible representations of negative numbers.

As mentioned in comments, the value of name is an address -- it is a pointer to memory with 4 chars -- and it is that address that is printed.
If you want to print the integer represented by those four bytes, then:

interpret the pointer as a pointer to int
dereference that pointer

So:
    printf("%d\n", *((int*) name));

Necessary to say you should never do this. The byte order and even the size of int is implementation dependent. You should not rely on one particular implementation, and instead maintain type consistency.
